# The products of the reaction between cupric oxide and nitric acid

Tags: acid-base

I am a third year student in junior high chool and I am having some difficulty finding information about the reaction of metal oxides and acids, and I cannot find a more accurate one online.
What exactly is produced by the reaction between curpic oxide and nitric acid?
Why does the concentration of nitric acid cause the products to be different?
Here're something I've found:
$\text{CuO}+2\text{HNO}_3\text{(dilute)}=\text{Cu(NO}_3\text{)}_2+\text{H}_2\text{O}$

$\text{CuO}+6\text{HNO}_3\text{(concentrated)}=\text{Cu(NO}_3\text{)}_2+4\text{NO}_2\uparrow+\text{O}_2\uparrow+3\text{H}_2\text{O}$

$2\text{CuO}+8\text{HNO}_3\text{(concentrated)}=2\text{Cu(NO}_3\text{)}_2+4\text{NO}_2\uparrow+\text{O}_2\uparrow+4\text{H}_2\text{O}$

Comment: See these questions: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97090/which-is-a-better-oxidising-agent-concentrated-nitric-acid-or-dilute-nitric-aci ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/17067/how-does-copper-reduce-dilute-nitric-acid-to-nitric-oxide-and-concentrated-nitri?rq=1 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158763/why-does-mercuryii-nitrate-form-only-when-using-concentrated-nitric-acid

Answer (score 1):

All your equations are the sums of the two following equations $$\ce{CuO + 2 HNO3 -> Cu(NO3)2 + H2O}$$ and $$\ce{4 HNO3 -> 4 NO2 + O2 + 2 H2O}$$. They can be added with any numerical parameter before being added.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, do similar ecomposition reactions occur on $\text{HCl}$ and $\text{H}_2\text{SO}_4$?

Comment: No ! $\ce{H2SO4}$ does not react with $\ce{HCl}$, because in the $19$th century $\ce{H2SO4}$ was used for synthesizing $\ce{HCl}$, at $300$°C, by the reaction : $\ce{H2SO4(l) + NaCl(s) -> Na2SO4(s) + 2 HCl(g)}$

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me a little (Pardon me, I am not a native speaker of English). I meant that do similar reactions occur when curpic oxide reacts with  $HCl$ and $H_2SO_4$ under different concentrations?

Comment: @DrThomasPeng. I am like you. I am not a native speaker of English. I will try to answer your question. Cupric oxide reacts with all acids, and in particular with $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$, according to : $$\ce{CuO + 2 HCl -> CuCl2 + H2O}$$   $$\ce{CuO + H2SO4 -> CuSO4 + H2O}$$ and it does not depend on the concentration. The reaction is the same at all concentrations of the acids

Comment: You have my gratitude. That's a very clear explanation.